# PHP MySQL Query to get results Thursday to Wednesday Last Week

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query results from last week from Thursday to Wednesday.

Today is the 18th which is Sunday, the first day of the week in PHP terms. My Code is not working because it restarts on Sunday. My IF statement is not working and my week modifier (-1 Week) is not working. Every week should go from thursday to thursday which ends at midnight on Wednesday. The results I am getting is today's results, but it should be going back to just this last thursday, subtracting -1 week, and pulling those results ending just this last thursday.

It should be pulling data between these dates
2015-1-8 thru
2015-1-14

But it's pulling from 2015-1-15 thru 2015-1-21 and not suppose to.

```
 <div class="subtitle">Last Week (12AM Thur to 12AM Thur)</div>
 <div class="totamt">$<?php  
   require_once 'wp-content/themes/azure-basic/connectvars.php';
   $dbc = mysqli_connect(CDB_HOST, CDB_USER, CDB_PASSWORD, CDB_NAME);

   /* Last Week */
     $twoWeeksAgoStart = new DateTime("Thursday last week");
     $twoWeeksAgoEnd = new DateTime("Wednesday");
     $today = new DateTime("now");
     $day = $today->format("1");

     if ($day == "Sunday" || $day == "Monday" || $day == "Tuesday" || $day == "Wednesday") {

     //This DOES NOT WORK from Sunday to Wednesday
     $twoWeeksAgoStart->modify("- 1 week");
     $twoWeeksAgoEnd->modify("- 1 week");

     } else {

     //This DOES actually works on Thursday through Saturday Night
     $twoWeeksAgoStart->modify("+7 days");   
     $twoWeeksAgoEnd->modify("- 1 week");
    }

  $startdates = $twoWeeksAgoStart->format( 'Y-m-d' );
  $enddates = $twoWeeksAgoEnd->format('Y-m-d');


 $query = "SELECT SUM(amountoffeeearned) as totalamount FROM commissioninfo WHERE thedate BETWEEN '$startdates' AND '$enddates'";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 ?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit? For example, on which day should the "last week" be changing? For example, on this coming Thursday should the last week be the 15th through the 21st?

Comment: I need the results for the week prior. 8th through the 14th.

Comment: But it seems to change when we get past Sunday. It starts a new week and goes from 15-21st. Should stay at the week prior until Wednesday night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it thoroughly but it might worth the try. Let me know if it works:

```
$minus = (date('D') !== 'Thu') ? "-1 week" : "";// Thursday check
$startdates = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$minus last Thursday"));
$enddates = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Wednesday"));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will not work on Thursdays it looks like. When testing it, if I made the date this Thursday the 22nd, it made dates of 01/08/2015-01/21/2015.

Comment: Actually Thursday through Saturday night. How would I say if this is Thursday through Saturday, then us a different format?

Comment: I've added a check in case today is Thursday: if it is it's not necessary the -1 week

Comment: I placed your code in the IF statement and left the rest. I also had to change the day to digits in the IF Statement and now it seems to be working great.

Comment: The updated code works great! It took me 20 days to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: @user2593040 you're welcome :) please, vote up if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I did some light testing, and I believe this may work for you:

```
if(date('N') == 4){
    $startdates = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Thursday"));
    $enddates = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));
}else{
    $startdates = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Thursday -1 week"));
    $enddates = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Thursday - 1 day"));
}
```

It checks if today is Thursday and if it is then it uses "last Thursday" and the current day -1 day to get the week. Any other day, it uses last Thursday - 1 week and last Thursday - 1 day to get the timeframe. As if today were say Friday the 23rd, in PHP's mind last Thursday is the day before (the 22nd) and on Thursday last Thursday is the preceding week's Thursday.

Hope this works and helps!